# How to click the below element in selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I would like to click on the below "sign in" option using selenium webdriver in python. Can someone help me on this?

```
<div class="item-4TFSfyGO item-ykcJIrqq item-50IqnBef withIcon-4TFSfyGO withIcon-ykcJIrqq" data-name="header-user-menu-sign-in"><div class="icon-4TFSfyGO"><svg height="28" viewbox="0 0 28 28" width="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M17.5 9c0 1.14-.3 1.99-.79 2.54-.46.52-1.27.96-2.71.96s-2.25-.44-2.71-.96A3.74 3.74 0 0 1 10.5 9c0-1.14.3-1.99.79-2.54.46-.52 1.27-.96 2.71-.96s2.25.44 2.71.96c.5.55.79 1.4.79 2.54zM19 9c0 2.76-1.45 5-5 5s-5-2.24-5-5 1.45-5 5-5 5 2.24 5 5zm-8 8.5h6c2.04 0 3.1.5 3.76 1.1.69.63 1.11 1.55 1.5 2.8.13.42.04.95-.29 1.4-.33.46-.8.7-1.22.7H7.25c-.43 0-.89-.24-1.22-.7a1.61 1.61 0 0 1-.3-1.4 6.08 6.08 0 0 1 1.51-2.8c.65-.6 1.72-1.1 3.76-1.1zm6-1.5h-6c-4.6 0-5.88 2.33-6.7 4.96-.58 1.89.97 4.04 2.95 4.04h13.5c1.98 0 3.53-2.15 2.95-4.04C22.88 18.33 21.6 16 17 16z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></div><div class="labelRow-4TFSfyGO labelRow-ykcJIrqq"><div class="label-4TFSfyGO">Sign in</div></div></div>
```

**EDIT:**
I usually find the XPATH and `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, button).click()` to click on buttons/hyperlinks.
In this page, after loading it, I was able to click on the "user" icon using `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/button[1]").click()` after which it shows menu with "sign in" option. I couldnt find the XPATH for that in firefox using "Inspect" option.
Then I saved the html page and checked the definition of "sign in" option and didnt find any button/hyperlink definition in it. So, I would like some help on this to proceed further. Thanks

Comment: Is there any specific code that you've tried and did not work for you?

Comment: Also, if possible update the question with the link to the page.

Comment: @cruisepandey https://in.tradingview.com/ is the page...
Have updated my question with whatever I have tried so far. Thanks

Comment: Please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click on sing in button using the below `CSS_SELECTOR` with `explicit waits`:

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)


driver.get("https://in.tradingview.com/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Open user menu']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-name='header-user-menu-sign-in' and contains(.,'Sign in')]"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: I was able to reach till this point using "driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/button[1]").click()". My problem is in clicking the "Sign In" option in the menu displayed on the right. Thanks

Comment: okay for that you will have to add one more command (update above as well)`wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-name='header-user-menu-sign-in' and contains(.,'Sign in')]"))).click()`, this should work. I would also recommend you to use relative xpath than absolute xpath `/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/button[1]` like this. Also, Explicit waits are more reliable than just having `driver.find_element`